# CSS Unordered list position respective elements together

Tags: css, html-lists, css-position

I am having a problem getting this to function the way I want and could use a little help. I have 2 images and 2 captions in an unordered list and I would like the captions to be displayed over the image but when I use positioning everything just ends up stacked on top of each other.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="image1.png" />
        <div>Caption 1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="image2.png" />
        <div>Caption 2</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li {
    position: relative;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    width: 100%
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Everything just stacks on top of each other. The expected output is for 2 separate images on the page with a caption overlapping the bottom portion of each image.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks ok to me. Just fixed minor syntax issues.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/bQMBG/

```
li {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    color: #fff;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a look at this for me!! I am using Drupal Views module to create a custom block with the above HTML. I realized I was having so much trouble because it was adding a DIV wrapper around the img. Everything is corrected and it looks great with the CSS you posted! Thanks again!!

Comment: You missed the colon in the div's "left" attribute :)

Comment: Thanks, Shylo. Fixed.